# μ-Law algorithm implementation

Tags: audio, codec, naudio

Here is Mu-Law encoder taken from NAudio. The question is how is this formula same with the code? I can understand that MuLawCompressTable is actually the Log but I dont get the thing about mantissa why it is taken as is.

[image]

```
    private const int cBias = 0x84;
            private const int cClip = 32635;

            private static readonly byte[] MuLawCompressTable = new byte[256] 
            {
                 0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
                 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
                 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
                 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
                 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
                 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
                 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
                 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
            };

 public static byte LinearToMuLawSample(short sample)
        {
            //We get the sign
            int sign = (sample >> 8) & 0x80;
            if (sign != 0)
                sample = (short)-sample;
            if (sample > cClip)
                sample = cClip;


            sample = (short)(sample + cBias);    

            int exponent = (int)MuLawCompressTable[(sample >> 7) & 0xFF];
            int mantissa = (sample >> (exponent + 3)) & 0x0F;
            int compressedByte = ~(sign | (exponent << 4) | mantissa);

            return (byte)compressedByte;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.  See the Wikipedia page on mu-law, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulaw

> There are two forms of this algorithm—an analog version, and a quantized digital version.

You quote the formula for the "analog" version - a compressive mapping from -1..1 to -1..1, which emphasizes the basic idea of mu-law, i.e. that the quantized value encodes more detail (uses a smaller quantization step) for smaller values, so the introduced quantization error is roughly proportional to the overall amplitude of the signal.

The "digital" version is a piecewise-linear approximation to this basic idea, with some additional shifts to further simplify processing.

Here's a plot comparing the two.  You can see the stairsteps in the green line (mu_digital) corresponding to the discrete 7-bit values, and you also spot the different linear sections approximating the smooth blue line.

[image: analog and digital mulaw plot]

Comment: Looking the table again helped me more to understand it.